# Triangle groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

I am having a hard time finding references (apart from wikipedia) for the geometric interpretation of triangle groups $T_{a,b,c} = \langle x,y \mid |x|=a, |y|=b, |xy|=c \rangle$. How can these groups be visualized in the Euclidean, spherical and hyperbolic cases?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can see Magnus' book, *Noneuclidean tesselations and their groups*.

Comment: Jeff Weeks' Kalediotile is a program that handles visualization of the action of these groups as well. It's available here: http://geometrygames.org/KaleidoTile/index.html